# Oracle ODP.NET problems calling package procedure with parameters

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle10g, odp.net, oracle9i

**Problem:**
Trying to call a packaged stored procedure, but the call is failing depending on the values of the parameters.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

**Procedure Definition:**

```
procedure DUP_EXACT (
    SSN in VARCHAR2, 
    LASTNAME in VARCHAR2, 
    FIRSTNAME in VARCHAR2, 
    MASTERRECORD IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    C_Table out sp_cursor)
```

**Parameter Creation:**

```
    For Each SearchParameter In SearchParameters
        ValueParameter = New OracleParameter

        ValueParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        ValueParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
        ValueParameter.ParameterName = SearchParameter.ParameterFieldName

        If Not SearchParameter.TransformedFieldValue = Nothing Then
            ValueParameter.Value = SearchParameter.TransformedFieldValue
        Else
            ValueParameter.Value = String.Empty
        End If

        ExactMatchSearchParameters.Add(ValueParameter)
    Next

    Dim MasterRecordParameter As New OracleParameter()

    MasterRecordParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    MasterRecordParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    MasterRecordParameter.ParameterName = "MASTERRECORD"
    MasterRecordParameter.Value = DBNull.Value

    ExactMatchSearchParameters.Add(MasterRecordParameter)

    Dim TableParameter As New OracleParameter

    TableParameter.ParameterName = "C_Table"
    TableParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor
    TableParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

    ExactMatchSearchParameters.Add(TableParameter)
```

**Execution:**

```
Using Command As OracleCommand = 
        New OracleCommand(
            QualifiedProcedureName, 
            Me.Database.Connection)

    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    'Command.AddToStatementCache = False '

    For Each Parameter In Parameters
        Command.Parameters.Add(Parameter)
    Next

    Command.Connection.Open()

    'Command.Connection.FlushCache() '

    Using Reader As OracleDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader()
```

**Example Successes & Failures:**

```
*** SUCCESS ***
[SSN]: "6#######0"
[LASTNAME]: "W_____x"
[FIRSTNAME]: "D______e"
[MASTERRECORD]: ""
[C_Table]: ""

*** FAILURE ***
[SSN]: "2#######_1"
[LASTNAME]: "C____n"
[FIRSTNAME]: "L___e"
[MASTERRECORD]: ""
[C_Table]: ""

*** FAILURE ***
[SSN]: "5#######5"
[LASTNAME]: "C_______s"
[FIRSTNAME]: "R_____o"
[MASTERRECORD]: ""
[C_Table]: ""

*** SUCCESS ***
[SSN]: "6#######0"
[LASTNAME]: "P___a"
[FIRSTNAME]: "N______r"
[MASTERRECORD]: ""
[C_Table]: ""
```

**Additional Testing:**

I tried running a trace to see what ODP.NET was actually sending to the database in the parameters, but the tracefiles did not provide any meaningful information (IE: the actual parameter values)

```
TIME:2013/02/14-14:10:19:678 
TID:231c  
OpsSqlPrepare2(): 
SQL: Begin PACKAGE.DUP_EXACT(:v0, :v1, :v2, :v3, :v4); End;
```

**Example Parameter Values:**

```
?Command.Parameters(0)
{SSN}
    ArrayBindSize: Nothing
    ArrayBindStatus: Nothing
    CollectionType: None {0}
    DbType: String {16}
    Direction: Input {1}
    InvalidPrecision: 100
    InvalidScale: 129
    InvalidSize: -1
    IsNullable: False
    m_bOracleDbTypeExSet: False
    m_bReturnDateTimeOffset: False
    m_collRef: {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection}
    m_commandText: ""
    m_direction: Input {1}
    m_disposed: False
    m_enumType: ORADBTYPE {4}
    m_modified: False
    m_oraDbType: Varchar2 {126}
    m_paramName: "SSN"
    m_paramPosOrName: ""
    m_saveValue: Nothing
    MaxScale: 127
    MinScale: -84
    Offset: 0
    OracleDbType: Varchar2 {126}
    OracleDbTypeEx: Varchar2 {126}
    ParameterEnumType: ORADBTYPE {4}
    ParameterName: "SSN"
    Precision: 0
    Scale: 0
    Size: 0
    SourceColumn: ""
    SourceColumnNullMapping: False
    SourceVersion: Current {512}
    Status: Success {0}
    UdtTypeName: ""
    Value: "4#######0" {String}
```

Comment: Have you tried a test where you manually build your OracleParameter objects with hard coded values, and add them to your OracleCommand? ... to rule an issue with your dynamic code.

Comment: That resolved 1 case but another is still failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is that there is a bug in Oracle 9.2.0.6.0 that causes intermitten VARCHAR2 binding errors.  Awesome.**

[This forum post finally gave me the answer:](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1456123)

> Is this behavior consistent or intermittent? If intermitten, and
>   your db is 9206, you're likely encountering the following rdbms bug:
>
> Bug.4015165 (74) REGRN SCALAR VARCHAR2 IN BINDS WITH DIFFERENT SIZE
>   RANDOMLY FAILS WITH ORA-06502
>
> and should be resolved by patching your database.
>
> I'm not sure why, but ODP seems to encounter this bug a lot more than
>   other drivers.
>
> If not intermittent, or if you are using a current patch level of
>   database, a complete testcase would probably be best.
>
> Cheers, 
>   Greg

A quick check verified that the version we are on is affected:

```
select * from v$version;
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production       
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production                            
CORE    9.2.0.6.0   Production                                          
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.6.0 - Production           
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
```

Luckily our production servers are 10g, so we finally updated our dev server to 10g as well, and viola, no more problems.

**Answer Trail:**

[Parameter issue with Oracle RefCursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210956/parameter-issue-with-oracle-refcursor)

[Oracle ODP.NET Forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=146&start=0)

[ODP.NET Forum Thread "Error ORA-06502 PL/SQL"](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1456123)

Answer (score 1):

It might sound odd, but make sure the oracle params are added as they appear in the query. I've ran into this issue a few times in the past (often in the migration to ODP.NET)

Comment: Good reminder, but I'm pretty sure they are in order in the query, as the debug code that printed the success / failure messages was printing them out from a for loop of the parameters

Comment: The default is bind by position, but you can set the bindbyname property to true to assist in migrating code from other providers such as the OracleClient.