# Purging an Oracle Advanced Queue in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, advanced-queuing

I am developing a Windows Service that uses an Oracle Advanced Queue to control it. Command objects will be placed on the queue and the service will dequeue it and attempt to carry out the task. In order to control the service I also developed a small command application. This application will put commands on the queue but I would also like it to be able to purge the queue by calling dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table whenever a button is pushed. I have tried this two ways. First I tried:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("queue_table", "PRISMPRO_Q_TAB");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("purge_condition", DBNull.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("purge_options", DBNull.Value);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table has 3 parameters and I passed it 3 arguments. Furthermore, they are of the correct type. There is no reason as best as I can tell why this error should be happening. I was unable to figure out how to get this to go away so I tried the following:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "exec dbms_aqadm.purge_queue_table('PRISMPRO_Q_TAB', NULL, NULL)";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

and got the error:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

The SQL Statement is not invalid. It runs just fine in SQL Developer. So in either case I am getting error messages that unless I am missing something I shouldn't be getting. I can't figure out a way around this. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or how to work around this?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? According to [SO - problems calling package with varchar2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883627/oracle-odp-net-problems-calling-package-procedure-with-parameters), there is bug with in Oracle 9.2.0.6.0 that causes intermitten VARCHAR2 binding errors.

Comment: We are on version 12c

Answer (score 0):

I bet you just need:

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not it. When I originally wrote this application, I used Oracle's ODP.net which use positional binding. However when i ran into this problem I tried using Microsoft's System.Data.OracleClient and that didn't fix the problem either. System.Data.OracleClient binds parameters by name by default.